# Brouwer's fixed point theorem and the one-point topology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, intuition

*I posted this question last week on Math SE and got upvotes and helpful comments that allowed me to make the question more precise https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765546/810513. As I did not get an answer to this question, please allow me to ask it on MO:*

In the 2-dimensional case, Brouwer's fixed point theorem (BFPT) says that every continuous function $D^2\to D^2$ has a fixed point, where $D^2$ is the disk.

Now fix a particular topology: pick some point $x_0\in D^2$ and use it to define the one-point topology $\cal T_0$ on $D^2$: it includes all sets $A$ with $x_0\in A$, and the empty set. (This is indeed a topology, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology).

With respect to $\cal T_0$, a self map $D^2\to D^2$ is continuous if and only if it is constant or has $x_0$ as a fixed point. So, for every self map on $D^2$, continuity with respect to $\cal T_0$ means that a fixed point exists. Hence the BFPT is trivially true, by definition of $\cal T_0$.

In conclusion, there are topologies where BFPT is a theorem that requires proof, and there is a topology $\cal T_0$ where BFPT is true just by definition.

> This gives $\cal T_0$ a special place among all possible topologies on $D^2$: it is the topology that makes BFPT trivial. Does such a situation or property have a name? Does it have a category theory interpretation (maybe like "universal property")?

> I feel there is a certain *equivalence* between BFPT and $\cal T_0$ here. They characterize each other in a certain way: $\cal T_0$ makes BFPT trivially true by definition, and BFPT links continuity and fixed points (like $\cal T_0$ does). Can this sense of equivalence be expressed rigorously?

I am struggling to express this property and my sense of "equivalence" more precisely and thus understand it better - I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

*EDIT:* Thank you for great comments! They are extremely helpful. I edited and corrected my question to reflect them.

Comment: "Continuity and having the fixed point $x_0$ are one and the same thing here.", that's not true, is it? For example if $x_1$ is any other point, the constant map to $x_1$ is also continuous with respect to your $x_0$-topology, since all preimages are either empty or everything. But this does not have $x_0$ as fixed point.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that literally as written, your topology is not a topology, since the empty set also needs to be open.

Comment: @AchimKrause thank vou very much for your remark about the empty set! I corrected it now in my question. The one-point topology which I am describing here should indeed be a proper topology, it is sometimes called the "particular point topology". Please see the related Wikipedia article.

Comment: It is still not true that continuity and having fixed point $x_0$ are one and the same thing for that topology. For any topology any point is the unique fixed point for some continuous map (e. g. the constant map with value this point).

Comment: What you really want to say is that a self map is continuous with respect to this topology if and only if it is either constant or has $x_0$ as a fixed point. Here is an argument that a continuous map which doesn't fix $x_0$ must be constant: if $f$ is continuous and sends $x_0$ to $x_1\neq x_0$, then for any $x_2\neq x_1$, the pre-image $f^{-1}(\{x_0, x_2\})$ doesn't contain $x_0$, so must be empty. Thus $x_1$ is the only element of the image of $f$.

Comment: I don't sense any real equivalence here between continuity and having a fixed point, since there are many non-constant self maps which fix other points but don't fix $x_0$. I think the best we can say is "BFPT is easier to prove when our topology is a lot simpler." My guess is that there isn't anything deeper going on.

Comment: @MattFeller thanks a lot for your two comments! Also thanks to the others giving the same comment about the constant function - I will edit and correct. Regarding your second question, let me think about your statement „BFPT is easier to prove when our topology is a lot simpler“

Comment: Aside from the question for whether BFPT is true (trivially or not), I think your argument doesn't establish that it is.  You say:  every function with $x_0$ as fixed point is continuous in this topology (which is true); but you conclude:  every function that is continuous in this topology has $x_0$ as fixed point.  As others have pointed out, that's false, but, even if you revise to a true statement, it doesn't follow from your argument.  (Could you also define mathematically "theorem" versus "trivially true"?  It seems a judgement.  Maybe Brouwer found it trivially true in usual topology!)

Comment: @R.Srivastava the constant function has a fixed point...

Comment: The first paragraph is perplexing to me. You write "This is valid for any choice of topology." But the BFPT is a fact about the standard Euclidean topology on $D^2$, and certainly fails for other topologies. To be explicit, consider the indiscrete topology on $D^2$, in which only the empty set and $D^2$ itself are open. Every function $D^2\rightarrow D^2$ is continuous in this topology, but there are certainly functions from $D^2$ to itself with no fixed point (e.g. a function that maps the origin to $(0,1)$ and rotates the rest of the disk by 90 degrees).

Comment: The example I gave above is explicit, but you can get lots of topologies on $D^2$ in which BFPT fails by simply looking for topological spaces of the same cardinality as $D^2$ for which BFPT fails, e.g. the real line. If you choose a bijection between $D^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (which presumably requires the Axiom of Choice), then there's a unique topology on $D^2$ making this function a homeomorphism, and the BFPT will fail (simply because on $\mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x) = x+1$ is continuous and has no fixed point).

Comment: (I now see that my comments are about a line added in a recent edit, which explains why the other commenters didn't complain about this.)

Comment: You say that every continuous $f : D^2 \to D^2$ has a fixed point, for any choice of topology on $D^2$. How about the discrete and the indiscrete topologies?

Comment: @DanRamras thank you very much for your comprehensive comment and your example. You are right! My statement was wrong and I have removed it now.